# Local Reports in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2022, rdlc

I took over an application (WinForms) developed a few years ago that needs to run on older computers as well. In Visual Studio 2022, when I modify a report, the schema changes from 2010/01 to 2016/01. However, another issue I'm encountering is that the forms with parameters are throwing this error, when I set the parameters for the report.: **An error occured during local report processing**

I attempted to install various NuGet packages, specifically trying to download Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, but I encountered no success. Is there a specific build version or configuration required for this task? It's worth noting that the application functions correctly on the former employee's computer with Visual Studio 2015, but I'm facing challenges in replicating this on my system.

Comment: There is a similar post here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ee65080a-2a4e-4419-ae10-b5bb3f5f5738/vs2017-report-viewer-2016-schema-in-rdlc?forum=visualstudiogeneral. In addition, what is the complete error of "An Error Occured During Local Report Processing", which is more conducive to everyone to help you